# Scrapy - generate item which a filed is list and elements of the list field come from multiple page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The item has two field:

```
class Item(scrapy.Item):
    field1 = scrapy.Field() 
    field2 = scrapy.Field()  # list field
```

and the crawl sequence is:

```
class TestSpider(scpapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ["http://example.com/index"]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = Item()
        field1_xpath = "xxx"
        field1_href = response.xpath(field1_xpath).extract_first()
        field2_xpath = "xxx"
        field2_href = response.xpath(field2_xpath).extract_first()
        field2_list = list()
        item["field2"] = field2_list
        request = scrapy.Request(field2_href, callback=self.parse_field2)
        request.meta["item"] = item
        request.meta["field1_href"] = field1_href
        yield request

    def parse_field2(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]
        field1_href = response.meta["field1_href"]
        field2_items_xpath = "xxx"

        for field2_item_href in response.xpath(field2_items_xpath).extract():
            request = scrapy.Request(field2_item_href, callback=self.parse_field2_item)
            request.meta["item"] = item
            request.meta["field1_href"] = field1_href
            yield request

    def parse_field2_item(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]
        field1_href = response.meta["field1_href"]
        field2_item_xpath = "xxx"
        field2_item = response.xpath(field2_item_xpath).extract_first()
        item["field2"].append(field2_item)

        request = scrapy.Request(field1_href, callback=self.parse_field1)
        request.meta["item"] = item
        yield request

    def parse_field1(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]
        field1_xpath = "xxx"
        field1 = response.xpath(field1_xpath).extract_first()
        item["field1"] = field1

        return [item]
```

In this sequence, only one element of `field2` will be scraped and then it will crawl the `field1`.

I want to send request of `field1` at the end of all `field2` items has appended to `field2`. I can't find where to yield the request of `field1`.

The webpages structure as follows:

```
index
    introduction
    field2_item_list
        field2_item1
        field2_item2
        field2_item3

item = {"field1": content_from_introduction, "field2": [field_item1, field2_item2, field2_item3, ...]}
```

I visit index at first to get the link to introduction and field2_item_list(`parse`), yield request to field2_item_list. And visit field2_item_list to get links to field2_items(`parse_field2`), yield requests to field2_items. Then parse field2_items in `parse_field2_item`. I yield the request to `introduction` in `parse_field2_item`. But it can't collect all field2_items to construct item.

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit, your code is a bit hard to read with all of that filler.

Comment: @Granitosaurus I have updated some information.